# How do I set up LBRY App on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

Can I run the LBRY App on my Raspberry Pi which I have connected to my TV?
I want to watch movies and listen to music from LBRY, on my TV.

Comment: What LBTY app? Is this a Linux app? If the app and its documentation are available online you should include a link.

Answer (score 0):

From the [lbry website](https://lbry.io/get) you can find the download link for Linux, so yes, it should work.
But maybe also consider the [Open Source Media Center](https://osmc.tv/) which has a specific distribution for the raspberry pi.

Comment: The plain linux one will not work if there are native code compiled bits in there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a version for Pi being built, it's currently in beta and can be found at https://lbrypi.com/downloads

It looks like it is going to be a great addition to the lbry protocol

Comment: There's certainly one here: https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-desktop#install

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install LBRY App on raspberry pi but you have two ways to do it compile from source code, or download prebuild binaries. If running from source you also need build daemon for armhf arch. As for main app you need build it witch command `yarn build --arch=armv7l` After you build deb file you need apply manual fixes like change arch in control file inside deb file (armv7l to armhf).

Comment: This is a more thorough explanation, but I would like to see all the steps, like 1. 
2.
3.